# Reverse search in PowerShell ISE wanted

Tags: bash, powershell-ise

In Bash, you can reverse search your history using Ctrl-R and start typing. Is there a similar feature in Windows PowerShell ISE?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/103178/powershell-history-enhancements-readline ?

Comment: So the answer is typing `#` instead of `Ctrl-R`.

Comment: Edit: # does work :D MSC, feel free to post in the answer section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to press <kbd>#</kbd>, type the partial match of the wanted command and complete by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

To anyone visiting in May 2018 and beyond, Ctrl + R does work in Powershell now

[image]

Comment: True for Powershell in Windows 10, in Windows 7 it does not work. And when using Windows PowerShell ISE Ctrl+R opens a new script editing window. Do you know how to do it there?

Answer (score 0):

for me knowing that pressing    <kbd>#</kbd>string<kbd>Tab</kbd> in powershell works pretty the same as backward incremental search was usefull. [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_history?view=powershell-7.4)

- <kbd>#</kbd>string<kbd>Tab</kbd> - Search the history for  and returns the most recent match. If you press Tab repeatedly, it cycles through the
  matching items in your history.